# Create new row every 2 records using knockout foreach

Tags: javascript, html, css, knockout.js

I'm attempting to create a new row every two records using knockout virtual elements. My problem is that the odd record does not generate in between the two even indexes.

#### Here's my source HTML

```html
   <!--ko foreach:UDGroupboxes-->
    <!--ko if:$index()%2==0 || $index()==0-->
    <div class="row-fluid">
    <!--/ko-->
        <div class="panel form-horizontal span6">
            <div class="panel-heading"><span data-bind="text:$data.Caption"></span></div>
        </div>
     <!--ko if:$index%2()!=0 && $index()!=0-->
    </div>
    <!--/ko-->
    <!--/ko-->
```

#### The output HTML

```html
<div data-bind="attr:{id:Name}" class="tab-pane active" id="Tabsheet1">
    <!--ko foreach:UDGroupboxes-->
    <!--ko if:$index()%2==0 || $index()==0-->
    <div class="row-fluid">
    <!--/ko-->
        <div class="panel form-horizontal span6">
            <div class="panel-heading"><span data-bind="text:$data.Caption"></span></div>
        </div>
     <!--ko if:$index%2()!=0&&$index()!=0-->
    </div>
    <!--/ko-->

    <!--ko if:$index()%2==0 || $index()==0--><!--/ko-->

    <!--ko if:$index()%2==0 || $index()==0-->
    <div class="row-fluid">
    <!--/ko-->
        <div class="panel form-horizontal span6">
            <div class="panel-heading"><span data-bind="text:$data.Caption"></span></div>
        </div>
     <!--ko if:$index()%2!=0&&$index()!=0-->
    </div>
    <!--/ko-->
    <!--/ko-->
</div>
```

The panel should be generated no matter the condition. The condition only determines to open a new row on even numbers and close the row on odds.

Comment: Mistype for braces () in eighth row of html source.

Comment: I actually had caught that, just forgot to edit this post. Edited as of now.

Comment: IF I want to do this every 3 items, how will it be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Knockout binding only happen on elements, and virtual elements must also adhere to the element hierarchy. If we take your example and use indentation to show the element relation, it looks like this:

```html
<!--ko foreach:UDGroupboxes-->
    <!--ko if:$index()%2==0-->
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <!--/ko-->
            <div class="panel form-horizontal span6">
                <div class="panel-heading"><span data-bind="text:$data.Caption"></span></div>
            </div>
            <!--ko if:$index()%2!=0-->
        </div>
    <!--/ko-->
<!--/ko-->
```

The closing and opening virtual tags within the `div` are ignored by Knockout. So the above just has the effect of outputting every other item.

Here is a good answer for doing grouping of array items in Knockout: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10577599/1287183

Comment: Also `x%2==0 || x==0` is equivalent to `x%2==0` because `0%2` is always `0`.

Comment: True enough. Thank you Michael for the clarification. I knew this would not work once I had tested the code, but I wanted to ensure it was because of notation.

Answer (score 0):

You're better off supplying knockout with a multi-dimensional array.  This is a much cleaner solution and has less potential for quirky results.

Look at Example 2: Note 3: in the documentation:  http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: { data: categories, as: 'category' }">
    <li>
        <ul data-bind="foreach: { data: items, as: 'item' }">
            <li>
                <span data-bind="text: category.name"></span>:
                <span data-bind="text: item"></span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<script>
var viewModel = {
    categories: ko.observableArray([
        { name: 'Fruit', items: [ 'Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana' ] },
        { name: 'Vegetables', items: [ 'Celery', 'Corn', 'Spinach' ] }
    ])
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>
```