# nested if blocks within foreach not rendering as expected

Tags: knockout.js

Have the following template but it doesn't render as expected. Somethings up with knockout's control flow. The *name* property should be rendered in the *div* between to the two *if* statements but it doesn't. What am I missing?

```
<!-- ko foreach: userAddresses -->
    <div data-bind="text: name"></div> // this prints correctly
    <!-- ko if: shouldStartNewRow($index) -->
    <div class="row">
    <!-- /ko -->
        <div class="col-xs-4 text-left"><div data-bind="text: name"></div></div> // nothing prints here
    <!-- ko if: shouldStartNewRow($index) -->
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

this produces:

```
<div>Joe blow</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 text-left"><div> </div></div> // missing Joe blow here. it does produce a single space
</div>
```

---

**Update:**
Created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/StrandedPirate/2pomuqgt/) to show the problem. It appears that if don't neatly close all html within a conditional block this causes knockout to go haywire.

Comment: This has been answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18157118/1287183

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create new row every 2 records using knockout foreach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18156558/create-new-row-every-2-records-using-knockout-foreach)

Answer (score 0):

just try

```
<div data-bind="text: $data.name"></div>
```

also i think you cant have unclosed elements inside a comment if-block

so it should rather look like:

```
<!-- ko foreach: userAddresses -->
    <div data-bind="text: name"></div> 
    <!-- ko if: shouldStartNewRow($index) -->
    <div class="row"> 
        <div class="col-xs-4 text-left"><div data-bind="text: name"></div></div> 
    </div>
    <!-- ko ifnot: shouldStartNewRow($index) -->
        <div class="col-xs-4 text-left"><div data-bind="text: name"></div></div> 
    <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Tried that too, but still doesn't print.

Comment: setting up a fiddle would be a great help

Comment: If I move all code inside an `if` or `ifnot` block then it does render correctly, however by doing so I'll be repeating my template twice, ugh. This is a very watered down version of course. Does Sanderson define a rule about this behavior in the documentation? I can't seem to find it.