# Placing a Container Around Every 'n' Items in a Knockout JS foreach Loop

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I would like to construct the following HTML using a knockout JS foreach loop...

```
<div>
  <div>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
  </div>
  <div>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
  </div>
</div>
```

... where each 'article' is an item in the array.

I've tried the following, which seems logically sound, but it doesn't work - I'm assuming knockout is getting confused by the unbalanced tags inside the comments...

```
<div data-bind="foreach: articles()">
  <!-- ko: if ($index() % 3 == 0)
    <div>
  <!-- /ko -->

    <article></article>

  <!-- ko: if ($index() % 3 == 2)
    </div>
  <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Any thoughts on how I can achieve this would be appreciated!

Comment: I had the same problem, just with a `thead` and `tbody` I obviously only wanted to create once, based on the $index(). KO can only take care of well-formed elements. Be aware that using brackets in your binding will remove the auto-updating from your data-binding in your view: `foreach: articles()`. Simply go `foreach: articles`.

Answer (score 1):

My take on this when tackling similar problems has always been that the view-model has to be structured as closely to the view as possible, so that you're not doing logic in the view itself. So therefore the place to group your array of articles is using a `ko.computed` in the viewmodel to build a structure like:

```
groupedArticles = [
    [article1, article2, article3],
    [article4, article5, article6]
]
```

then in your view you can do:

```
<!-- ko foreach: groupedArticles -->
<div>
    <!-- ko foreach: $data -->
    <article></article>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Let me know if that makes sense or not; if not I can try to add a fiddle to demo it.

**Update**

I found a fiddle which used this pattern. I needed to upgrade KO to the latest version to get it to work, you can now try it using this: http://jsfiddle.net/hFPgT/160/

This is from the question, [How to get Knockout to group foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575751/how-to-get-knockout-to-group-foreach)

And the relevant code is:

```
this.grouped = ko.computed(function () {
        var rows = [], current = [];
        rows.push(current);
        for (var i = 0; i < this.items.length; i += 1) {
            current.push(this.items[i]);
            if (((i + 1) % 4) === 0) {
                current = [];
                rows.push(current);
            }
        }
        return rows;
}, this);
```

Comment: While this works, it's not pretty, since it mixes the display logic with the data.

Comment: can you explain more? A view-model is not entirely a model, after all. It's the model adapted into a structure suitable for rendering in the view. So by its very definition, it is the place where you mix display logic with data. If you want to get more separation, have a separate model by all means, and then a view-model and a view. Frameworks like knockback do this.

Comment: By the MVVM paradigm the data should be stored in the model, modified for viewing by the view-model and displayed by the view. So the correct approach would be to have a separate model and then consume that data in the view-model.

Comment: I agree with @sifriday. The view model exposes properties to be bound to the view and is where you would mix display logic. Where else would you do it?

Answer (score 1):

Like @sifriday, I would go for a separate computed array which I'd name `articleGroups` (or view). In my more recent understanding of Knockout, I found it most convenient to put all view-related logic (here: grouping) inside components' viewModels, so I built a component for it here.
The additional benefit is that you can pass parameters in the view; try the below snippet with different values for 'groupBy' for example.

```js
// setup
var articles = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++)
  articles.push({i: i+1, text: "text"});

// listview component
ko.components.register('article-view', {
  viewModel: function(params) {
    var groupBy = this.groupBy = ko.observable(params.groupBy);
    this.articleGroups = ko.computed(function() {
      var result = [], group = groupBy();
      ko.utils.arrayForEach(ko.unwrap(params.data), function(item, index) {
        if (index % group === 0) 
          result.push([item]);
        else 
          result[result.length-1].push(item);
      });
      return result;
    });
  },
  template: {element: 'article-group'}
});

// viewModel instantiation
VM = { articles: ko.observableArray(articles)};
ko.applyBindings(VM);
```

```css
body>div>div>div { border-bottom: 1px solid gray; padding-bottom: 10px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/template" id="article-group">
  <input type="number" data-bind="value: groupBy" min="1" max="50">
  <div data-bind="foreach: articleGroups, as: 'group'">
    <div data-bind="foreach: $data, event: {load: console.log($data)}">
      <article data-bind="text: i"></article>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
<div data-bind="component: {name: 'article-view', params: {groupBy: 5, data: articles}}"></div>
```