# Using knockout if binding inside a table

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I was trying to use the if binding inside a table and the 3rd column is not at all displaying the text where as the entries in the 1st column are getting displayed.

```
<table id="searchPanelForm" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" class="conttable" width="100%" border="0" data-bind="">
    <tbody>
        <!-- ko foreach: searchPanelArray -->
            <!-- ko if: $parent.isSearchEven($data.id) -->
                <tr>
                    <td class="col2" data-bind="text: $data.label"></td>
                    <td class="col3"><input type="text"></td>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko if: !$parent.isSearchEven($data.id) -->
                    <td class="col2" data-bind="text: $data.label"></td>
                    <td class="col3"><input type="text"></td>
                </tr>
            <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

`searchPanelArray` is populated through an ajax call and `isSearchEven` returns true or false when the index is even or odd respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knockout expects "containerless control flow syntax" to act like elements. They cannot start on the outside of an element and end inside the element. So from Knockout's point of view, the comments internal to `<tr>` are simply malformed and ignored. So this is what it looks like for Knockout:

```
<!-- ko foreach: searchPanelArray -->
    <!-- ko if: $parent.isSearchEven($data.id) -->
        <tr>
            <td class="col2" data-bind="text: $data.label"></td>
            <td class="col3"><input type="text"></td>
            <td class="col2" data-bind="text: $data.label"></td>
            <td class="col3"><input type="text"></td>
        </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

Logically, you want to group every two items in your array. You should create a computed observable the returns a new array with the two items grouped together.

```
this.searchPanelArrayGrouped = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    var result = [], source = this.searchPanelArray();
    for (var i = 0; i < source.length; i += 2) {
        if (i + 1 >= source.length) {
            result.push({left: source[i], right: {}});
        } else {
            result.push({left: source[i], right: source[i+1]});
        }
    }
    return result;
}, this);
```

Html:

```
<!-- ko foreach: searchPanelArrayGrouped -->
    <tr>
        <td class="col2" data-bind="text: $data.left.label"></td>
        <td class="col3"><input type="text"></td>
        <td class="col2" data-bind="text: $data.right.label"></td>
        <td class="col3"><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
<!-- /ko -->
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bg75xvxc/

Here is a related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10577599/1287183